# Continuity in the complex plane

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, continuity

I was reading a book where it is claimed that a sufficient condition for
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left|\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\theta_je^{ix j}\right|^2
\end{equation}
to be *continuous* and *is strictly positive* (over $(-\pi,\pi)$) is
\begin{equation}
0<\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|\theta_j|<\infty.
\end{equation}
Could anyone please explain this? Also, can we find a necessary condition as well?

Comment: What if you take all $\theta_j\equiv 0$? Then the function isn't strictly positive. There must be some missing conditions.

Comment: nice point! thanks very much. The condition is corrected

Comment: The condition is sufficient for $f$ to be continuous, since then $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \theta_k\cdot e^{ixk}$$ is a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions. It doesn't guarantee that $f$ is _strictly_ positive, however, e.g. take $\theta_0 = \theta_2 = 1$ and $\theta_k = 0$ for $k \notin \{0,2\}$. Then $f$ has zeros at $\pm \pi/2$.

Comment: thanks very much for your help. I guess it has to be assumed that $\theta_k\neq 0$ for all $k$ in advance..